# $E \supset K \supset k$, where $K \supset k$ is not algebraic. If $\alpha \in E$ is separable over K, .......

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

$E \supset K \supset k$, where $K \supset k$ is not algebraic. If $\alpha \in E$ is separable over K, show that $\alpha$ is separable over a finitely generated  extension of $k$

Comment: I know you're anxious to get your question answered, but you really ought to finish the sentence off.

Comment: Title cannot accommodate more than 150 words, dats y the dots. I have written the full question in the main body. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof impression: Consider the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.

Comment: Thanx. Is the condition $K \supset k$ is not algebraic redundant?